# Can I edit a layer from carto using carto.js (v4) and google maps api (Javascript)?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cartodb

I'm using Google Maps API to show a map and carto.js (v4) to get the layer from carto and render on it. I want to know if it's possible to make the layer editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Google Maps API provides [drawing tools](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) so you can approach the task in a similar way as described in this old (but still valid) [blog post](https://carto.com/blog/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/).

At the end is all about converting those frontend geometries into `INSERT` statements and use CARTO [SQL API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/), or more likely put some middelware in between to manage authentication and so on.